# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked') Angular Checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox

I need your help. I try, with the help of Angular, to check my checkbox whether it is pressed or not. If it is pressed, then I want to store the information in the database, and if not pressed, then do nothing. This code, which is shown, unfortunately gives me the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much)

html

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="saveMessage($event)" formControlName="checkboxInviteMessage">
   <mat-label>Save message</mat-label>
</mat-checkbox>
```

ts

```
saveMessage(event: any) {
   if (event.target.checked) {
    console.log('added');
    // Add data to database
   } else if (!event.target.checked) {
    console.log('unchecked');
    // Don't add data to database
   }
}
```

Comment: please take a look at the answer for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254524/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-checked

I think you need to follow the answers on that post.  One thing that could help you is specify the type of `event` better instead of using `any`

Comment: @JakeSmith, Thanks. I saw this question, but it didin't help me due to `target`)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but the accepted answer is straight from the link I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event parameter on your `saveMessage` is of type `MatCheckboxChange`, you don't have a `.target` in there.

For more information, I recommend reading the Angular Material docs: [link](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api)

```js
saveMessage(event: MatCheckboxChange) {
   if (event.checked) {
    // is checked
   } else {
    //.....
   }
}
```